# Why do I compare these two models using a likelihood ratio test?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I would appreciate it if someone could help me answer this.

I recently carried a logistic regression model using the following basic formula:
y ~ x + factor1 + factor2

My supervisor suggested it would be good to carry out a likelihood ratio test, comparing the above model output to the output from:
y ~ factor1 + factor2

I understand that the LRT compares the goodness-of-fit of two models, but I dont understand why the second model (null model) would be y ~ factor1 + factor2 and not y ~ x?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the difference between y ~ x + factor1 + factor2 and y ~ factor1 + factor2 is not significant, that would mean that x is not needed to predict y - is that what you want to check?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.  Yes the difference is significant, so I guess that means that x is necessary to predict y.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer says that x is not necessary to predict y and not the other way around.